# How to view entire contents of AWS Cloudwatch application logs?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

As shown in the scresnshot we see a snippet of messages. The one shown here "fits" due to its brevity: but other lines (contents of which I can not show due to privacy) are truncated at 212 characters.

I would like to just view the entire contents "raw" without the dropdown arrow or truncations. There was some way to do that but I can not find it at this point. Pointers appreciated.

[image]

Comment: This is from ECS console?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if I understood correct, but there is a checkbox called `View as text`.
When it is checked it will show you all log stream as pure text. Not as line collapsed anymore.

See it below.

[image: CloudWatch LogStream View as text]

Comment: That's what I had been looking for - but it does not show up for me ;(

Answer (score 1):

If you prefer CLI you can try something like this - https://github.com/lucagrulla/cw